# WordPress shortcode in content, output in sidebar?

Tags: loop, shortcode, sidebar

I would like to create a shortcode with parameters which can be used in the WordPress post content. If the shortcode is used, the content should be displayed in the sidebar area! I can suppress the output of the shortcode with `ob_end_clean()`, but I have no idea how to put this part into the sidebar (I do not want to use the `$_GLOBAL` var). Is there any clean way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna show the content in sidebar if current post content has the shortcode then you should try [`has_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) function. Here is a demonstration-

```
$content = get_the_content();
if( has_shortcode( $content, 'your-shortcode' ) ) {
    // The content has a [your-shortcode] short code, so this check returned true.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This **looks really great**, will have to try it though. If I understand this correct, this code part would run in my sidebar within the loop and check if the shortcode is present. I somehow did not think of this solution, just tried to get the output within the shortcode function into sidebar. How would I extract the shortcode with its parameters from the content and run the code?